# Is save() method commiting changes asynchronously?

Tags: django, asynchronous, django-models, celery

I have a simple `class` model with Django Admin (v. 1.9.2) like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Foo(models.Model):
    ...
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    bar = None
```

I have also overloaded `save()` method like this:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.bar = 1

    async_method.delay(...)

    super(Foo, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Here `async_method` is an asynchronous call to a task that will run on Celery, which takes the `users` field and will add some values to it.

At the same time, whenever a user is added to the `ManyToManyField`, I want to do an action depending on the value of the `bar` field. For that, I have defined a `m2m_changed` signal:

```
def process_new_users(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['action'] == 'post_add':
        # Do some stuff
        print instance.bar

m2m_changed.connect(process_new_users, sender=Foo.users.through)
```

And there's the problem. Although I'm changing the value of `bar` inside the `save()` method and before I call the asynchronous method, when the `process_new_users()` method is triggered, `instance.bar` is still `None` (initial value).

I'm not sure if this is because the `save()` method commits changes asynchronously and when the `process_new_users()` is triggered it has not yet commited changes and is retrieving the old value, or if I'm missing something else.

Is my assumption correct? If so, is there a way to force the values in `save()` be commited synchronously so I can *then* call the asynchronous method?

**Note**: Any alternative way of achieving this is also welcome.

---

**UPDATE 1**: As of @Gert's answer, I implemented a `transaction.on_change()` trigger so whenever the `Foo` instance is saved, I can safely call the asynchronous function afterwards. To do that I implemented this:

```
bar = BooleanField(default=False)   # bar has became a BooleanField

def call_async(self):
    async_method.delay(...)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.bar = True

    super(Foo, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    transaction.on_commit(lambda: self.call_async())
```

Unfortunately, this changes nothing. Instead of `None` I'm now getting `False` when I should be getting `True` in the `m2m_changed` signal.

Comment: The `save()` method does not commit changes asynchronously. You're invoking the asynchronous task before the model is (synchronously) saved, so it may or may not run after the model is actually saved.

Comment: @knbk any way I can run the asynchronous task once the `save()` method has successfully saved model changes? (not sure if there's a *post-save* hook for `save()` here...)

Answer (score 1):

You want to make sure that your database is up to date. In Django 1.9, there is a  new [`transaction.on_commit`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/transactions/#performing-actions-after-commit) which can trigger celery tasks.

Comment: Thanks. As I see it, there's no definition of *who* actually triggers the hook - I mean, is there a way to explicitly define that the method should be triggered only if the `save()` method has commited its changes?

Comment: @nKn the Django transaction system will trigger it. It knows when the transaction is actually committed into the database.

Comment: Nice, I'll give it a try and report results. Thanks.

Comment: Seems that the trigger method passed to `on_commit` doesn't accept parameters, nor can I manage to pass it `self` anyhow. Would you have an example how to use the `on_commit` trigger *inside* a class?

Comment: @nKn I believe this is possible: `transaction.on_commit(lambda: async_method.delay(self.id))`

Comment: Ok, that worked. I'm now calling the asynchronous method, but... the value of `instance.bar` inside the `m2m_changed` signal is still `None`. However, in the method called `on_commit` the value is the expected one. I don't know what else could be happening there... (no other place assigns value to the `bar` field).

Comment: @nKn is `bar` a field? Because otherwise it won't be saved in the database.

Comment: It is. Initially it didn't but I changed it to a field and the result is the same.